# How to set CHARACTER SET for writing to MySQL table using JDBC data source?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark JDBC for data ingestion into Mysql table. It's also creating a table if the table does not exist. Many of text has special characters. Ingestion is failing if encounter any special chars. I solved this problem by setting manually CHARACTER SET utf8 into MySQL table.

Is this possible to set `CHARACTER SET utf8` at the time of table creation in spark JDBC?

I am using DataFrames for saving data into MySQL.

```
df.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost")
  .option("dbtable", "spark.tweet")
  .option("user", "root")
  .option("password", "root")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `createTableOptions` option, e.g. `option("createTableOptions","CHARACTER SET utf8")`.

Quoting https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html:

> **createTableOptions** This is a JDBC writer related option. If specified, this option allows setting of database-specific table and partition options when creating a table (e.g., CREATE TABLE t (name string) ENGINE=InnoDB.). This option applies only to writing.

Comment: Do you know how to set  `SET NAMES utf8mb4` , thanks .

Comment: @roamer No idea, but would start with this `createTableOptions` option. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the charset is determined by your access into MySQL database. So the best way is setting the charset in the jdbc url like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}?user=${jdbcUsername}&password=${jdbcPassword}&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Already tried. It will not create a table with CHARACTER SET utf8.

Comment: Upvoted this because it's part of the answer. See below

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and there are two main changes I had to introduce:

1. The jdbc url must contain these 2: `&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`
2. The `createTableOptions` property mentioned by @JacekLaskowski, i.e.: `.option("createTableOptions", "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci"`

I've tried different combinations with and without some of the above and only using both the proper url and the option I could insert my Japanese characters in my MySql db. I am also using this driver `.option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` because first when I tried without this property it complained.

My database has another Character set so mind that this configuration only changes for your table.

Spark version is 2.4.